# PHPUnit / Laravel static class to method generating error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm having trouble with using PHPUnit to test my Laravel package that I am writing.  I am writing a class which extends the formbuilder, I have tried it against my own class and the parent class, (Illuminate\Html\Formbuilder), but I am getting the same error.

My test is

```
use Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder as Form;

class FormBuilderTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function test_basic_input() {
        $html = Form::text('test');

        $this->assertContains('input', $html);
    }
}
```

This fails with the following message

Non-static method Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder::text() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

I can't figure out what is going on with it, as far as I can tell this is the same static call that is made from blade in the framework.

Can anyone point me in the write direction with this one?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a static method as the error indicates.

Try:

```
$form = new Form;

$html = $form->text('test');
```

But I'm not familiar with Laravel, or with `Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder` and I'm not sure if it has a constructor that requires some options..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you alias `FormBuilder` to `Form`. That's only half correct. Because the `Form` class is the facade to access the `FormBuilder` and if you want to call it with a static call `Form::text()` you need to use the actual facade.

That means just remove

```
use Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder as Form;
```

And in case you have "namespace problems" add this use statement instead

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Form;
```

Alternatively you can also get a `FormBuilder` instance by using `$this->app`

```
$form = $this->app['form'];
$html = $form->text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out where I went wrong with this, I was running phpunit from the workbench directory in Laravel.  This wasn't picking up the necessary classes and I was trying to change my class to get around this.  I stored my test in the workbench/tests directory and pointed phpunit.xml to it, but ran it from the root Laravel project directory.  My class now looks much simpler.  Thanks for the help guys.

```
<?php
class FormBuilderTest extends TestCase {
    function test_basic_input() {
        $html = Form::text('text');

        $this->assertContains('input', $html);
    }
}
```